# nodejs tcp socket sends multiple data event

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to demonstrate the simpliest way of how an http server works by coding one with the tcp package. I did this several times before but today I'm facing an unexpected behavior, in that the `data` event from the socket object is fired *either one or multiple times randomly* for a similar request and I'm wondering why, and how to fix it properly.

Please note that I know I should use the stream way of processing data, which I do in my 2nd demonstration. The point is increasing complexity each time to make the presentation easier to follow.

Here's the server. As you can see, it's straight forward and easy to get.

```
const net = require('net')

const response = `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Foo: Bar

foobar
`

net.createServer(socket => {
  socket.on('data', buffer => {
    console.log('----- socket data', Date.now())
    console.log(buffer.toString())
    socket.write(response)
    socket.end()
    console.log('-----')
  })

  socket.on('end', () => console.log('----- socket end.'))
  socket.on('close', () => console.log('----- socket close.', '\n'))
}).listen(2000)
```

To test my server, I just open whatever web browser to `http://localhost:2000` and get the response ; but when using the following payload (using the javascript console of the browser), *sometimes* the data event would be triggered twice, ending up in a bug because the `write/end` process cannot proceed a second time.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ foo: "bar" }));
```

Here is a snap of the logs from the server, if anything could help :

```
----- socket data 1479133993862
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:2000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:2000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,id;q=0.2,ms;q=0.2,ko;q=0.2

{"foo":"bar"}
-----
----- socket end.
----- socket close.

----- socket data 1479133994515
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:2000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:2000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,id;q=0.2,ms;q=0.2,ko;q=0.2

{"foo":"bar"}
-----
----- socket end.
----- socket close.

----- socket data 1479133995166
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:2000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:2000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,id;q=0.2,ms;q=0.2,ko;q=0.2


-----
----- socket data 1479133995167
{"foo":"bar"}
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:167:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:212:5)
    at Socket.write (net.js:624:40)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/julien/Temp/foo.js:14:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

As you can see, the firsts 2 requests are fine, but the 3rd one is cut into 2 distinct parts. The headers of the request would be in one data event, and the body in an other.

I discussed this with few developers and we guess it could be related to the TCP stack of my OS, which is OSX Sierra if that could matter.

I couldn't see any other way to patch it than accumulating the buffer into a variable declared in an upper scope, then use an *ugly* timer trick which end up *something similar to* a cancellable setImmediate.

```
var timer = false, data = '';
socket.on('data', buffer => {
  data += buffer.toString();

  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => process(socket, data), 1)
})
```

Question is simple : I know this fix is very wrong in many ways, but I can't see other without using streams or http package. Could you enlight me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how TCP works. TCP is a stream of bytes. There are no packets with boundaries (or even requests) on application layer. A write call for n-bytes on one end of the connection could lead up to n 1-byte read calls on the other end. You have to be prepared that each read yields an arbitrary amount of bytes (up to the buffer size given to the read call - however as you get data pushed in node.js you can't influence that). If you need packets on application level you need to handle that yourself, e.g. by writing length-prefixed packets to the stream.

However HTTP does not require the notion of packets since it's already defined by the HTTP protocol where a header and the body ends.

Comment: Dont mistake me, I understand that completely.What i don't understand is the randomness of the cut between the events, and the effective precision of how the request is always cut in 2 half between headers and body.

Comment: Could be the case that client does 2 write calls, one for the header and one for the body. And that sometimes these are sent in combined fashion (if packets for the header haven't been sent before) and sometimes not.

Comment: But in general it shouldn't matter to you as a consumer of the stream since you can't rely on any behavior here.

Comment: I truely agree with you. I do think the same as in the client writes the bytes in 2 calls. But why would it be _sort of_ random choice ? Also for the fix, I couldn't see an other solution. Do you ?

Comment: It's a race condition. There are two writes to a buffer from a process. And in the background there's the OS which sends the content from the buffer to the network. If only after those two writes the network thread of the OS gets into action it would try to send anything available. If it's scheduled before it would only send the available header part. And if the network is congested it could be even less.

Comment: And the solution depends on what you want. Wait until the header or the complete request was received? You need a HTTP parser and the state machine for it. If the client does not use keepalive and closes the connection after sending the body it could be a workaround to wait for the end of stream instead.

Comment: I get the race condition, and as expected it sits into the OS layer which cannot be controlled, handled by my side of the code. About the solution, the client does use a keep-alive indeed. I tried to wait for the end of the stream, but the events are getting dispatched when the server calls for the `socket.end()` (that's why i logged them)

Comment: You won't get an end of stream if keepalive is active. So you need a parser to determine where the request ends. And for the exception: After receiving any part of the request you write the complete response and end the stream - which is valid. However once you get another piece of the request you try to write more data to the (already closed) outgoing stream. Which yields the exception. You can easily avoid this by tracking if you have already sent something.

Comment: Yep, i knew about the exception :) It is actually how i went to that "multiple data events are being fired" statement. A parser would be definitely more reliable than a timer indeed, but it requires a lot of extra code. I'll implement that in a 2nd intermediate iteration then :) Thanks a lot !